# Auto-login using nodm and ecrpytfs on the home folder

Tags: ubuntu, autologin, ecryptfs

I am trying to secure a Linux system to prevent offline access to the home directory (i.e. someone takes the HDD and mounts it on their system), which I've done with `ecryptfs`.

I use `nodm` which boots my system into a xsession running an application from that home directory. However, now that I've added `ecryptfs` my xsession doesn't launch... I have to go to a TTY and login first.

The question is, why can't I use ecrpytfs on my home directory, and have something like nodm (or another autologin) decrypt the home directory and run the application on bootup?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible.

Someone, or something has to supply the password for decryption. Obviously it can't be on your home directory (as that is encrypted). It *should* not be on your hard disk at all, as that would be pointless: An attacker could extract it from there.

So I don't see a way to make this automated (i.e, not requiring you) while preserving that only you can access it.

Comment: In the case of an auto-login like nodm, is it not using the password to get access?

Comment: The point is: If nodm was able to decrypt and log you in just after powering on the system, then any thief who got your hardware can do so. It might be possible to configure nodm todo so, but *you would lose all security gained by encrypting your harddisk*.